# Does 到了现在我才清楚了解当时的情况 imply that the situation is completely clear, or just that it's clearer than before?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

This question is related to [Writing critique request: Zhou Ziwang's father takes her to the "doctor"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwangs-father-takes-her-to-the-doctor).  In particular:

> English version: These days I have a clearer understanding of the situation, ...
>   My version: 现在我对那情况了解得更清楚 ...
>   [Tang Ho](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/35783/8099)'s version: 到了现在我才清楚了解当时的情况 ...

(I got rid of the brackets.)

The message I want to get across is that the situation is *clearer than before*, but this doesn't imply the situation is completely clear [there's still things which are unexplained].  It's why I chose to use 更清楚 which I intended to mean "more clear".

I'm unsure, but I think Tang Ho's version implies it's "completely clear".

**Question**: Does 到了现在我才清楚了解当时的情况 imply that the situation is completely clear, or just that it's clearer than before?

Comment: Is the Chinese version translated from English? If so, I think your Chinese version is okay -- direct translation from English. Otherwise, I agree with Tang Ho as it is the way we usually speak. I think you have come to a level to read as much you can, so you can build up your general feeling about Chinese. You might make mistakes here and there and that is normal.

Comment: That’s hard to answer: I write the Chinese directly, but I have a “English mind” so perhaps I’m mentally translating.  I’m thinking I won’t include the English in future; it seems to cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

"到了现在我才清楚了解当时的情况" means "the situation is completely clear for me now"

For "Now I understand more clearly about the situation back then" It should be "到了现在我才(更)清楚了解当时的情况"

It implies you had some understanding back then, but now this understanding is more clear.

I did not read your English translation. My editing is totally based on the impression I got from your Chinese writing.

Answer (score 1):

"clearer understanding" may not be accurate for your context. I would think you don't quite clear of the situation, and now you are clear.

In this case, it should go like: as a little girl, I don't quite understand the situation. But now I understand it. In Chinese, it could be: 我那时年纪小还不太懂，现在我才清楚是怎么回事。