# Writing critique request: Zhou Ziwang gets an injection from the "doctor"

Tags: writing-critique

Continuing from [part 3](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwangs-father-takes-her-to-the-doctor) (with the story starting at [part 1](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-and-the-revolutionary-new-technology)):

> 我们到了[医务室](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8C%BB%E5%8A%A1%E5%AE%A4)，这家楼看起来像实验室，而并不是像普通的医院。我看着我爸，他似乎已经对这个地方很熟悉，甚至知道怎么走。他说了“我的朋友在这儿工作”。我们一进去就看到医生了，而他带我们去他的办公室。医生立刻从桌子的抽屉中取出了一只[注射器](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B3%A8%E5%B0%84%E5%99%A8)，说“这会解决你的体重问题 ”。我有奇怪的感觉，但是我爸悄悄地说“我已经告诉了他你来这儿的原因”。虽然我当时还[有所](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9C%89%E6%89%80)怀疑，但我就只是相信父母[而已](http://youdao.com/w/%E8%80%8C%E5%B7%B2)，因此我让他给我[注射](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B3%A8%E5%B0%84)。没有发现了立即而明显的后果，所以然后医生就走了，而我们回家了。

Please critique my writing.  New words for me are in links.  I'm at an "almost mastered HSK4" level.

I'm afraid 一进去就[...] is too often used in relation to premature ejaculation (一进去就射了), which would be totally inappropriate here.  But maybe what I've written is okay.

Also I'm not sure if 而已 is appropriate.

I won't include an English version: that's not the point of this exercise.  I'm fairly confident it's understandable (or at least if it needs modifying, it won't require much back-and-forth in the comments).

Comment: "一进去就射了" lmao bro......

Comment: (It's very hard to "accept" an answer to this question [and others like it].  They're helpful in different ways.)

Comment: 注射—> 打针，注射器—>针管，后果—>效果/现象

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to explain this one. 栋 for a building and 座 for a certain kind of building?

> 我们到了医务室，这**家**(**栋**)楼看起来像(**座**)实验室

像 is a verb in Chinese so you don't add 是. Alternatively use 像是 as a single phrase.

> 而并不**是**(remove)像普通的医院

的 should be removed, I believe, so is 了. Also I would reverse the order to `My friend works here', he says. (“我朋友在这儿工作, 他说)`.

> 他说了“我的朋友在这儿工作”.

Reorder 了? `我们一进去就看到了医生`

> 我们一进去就看到医生了,

Not sure about 而, because I don't feel any logical relation here. Maybe use a word for temporal relation, e.g. 立刻, `他立刻带我们去了他的办公室` (adding 了 for past tense)

> 而他带我们去他的办公室。

I would use `我感觉有些奇怪` (I feel somehow strange) rather than `我有奇怪的感觉`(I have some strange feelings).

> 我有奇怪的感觉，但是我爸悄悄地说“我已经告诉了他你来这儿的原因”。

而已 is fine I think, but maybe 当时 to the "believe" part, because I think that part need it more. Also 注射了

> 虽然我当时还有所怀疑，但我就只是相信父母而已，因此我让他给我注射。

没有立即发现明显的后果("Didn't immediately see obvious result"). But not sure about the "发现". Here you are expecting to "feel" something, e.g. `没有立即感到明显的变化`(Didn't immediately feel any difference). Or just "没什么明显的感觉" (Didn't feel anything noticeable)

> 没有发现了立即而明显的后果

Again I don't feel the logical relationship here, so remove 所以 and 而, maybe add 也(also). "然后医生就走了，我们也回家了" ("Then the doctor left, so did we")

> 所以然后医生就走了，而我们回家了。

Answer (score 3):

The sentences are short, implying the passage is colloquial. However, its style doesn't accord to daily language, which makes it translationese.

我爸就带我去了医院，但比起医院那座建筑看起来更像研究所。我爸似乎已经很熟悉这里了，他根本没有问路。哦，我想起他说过有朋友在这里工作。最后我们到了一个房间，进去就看到了医生，见了我们立刻带往了他办公室。医生从抽屉里取出一支注射器，告诉我说打了以后就不会有体重问题了。我感到十分奇怪，但爸爸小声解释说他早就跟医生说过了。听了这话我虽然仍然怀疑，但出于对父亲的信任我没有拒绝注射。打完之后没什么特别的感觉，但医生确定已经完成了，于是走掉了，所以我们也回家了。

Comments:

It seems that you are not used to use link words, so sometimes it's weird in logic.

实验室 is a room complex, while 研究所 is a building complex.

一**支**注射器

"这会解决你的问题" We don't say like that, which I have only heard in translation works.

- 这并不能解决你的问题。√
- 这解决得了你的问题吗？√
- 这样你的问题就解决了。√
- 你还有什么问题没解决？√
- 这不会解决你的问题的。√
- 这会解决你的问题。x
- —— hard to say why.

"我已经告诉了他你来这儿的原因" Oh, it's worse.

- 你为什么要来我已经告诉过他了。
- 我已经告诉过他你为什么要来了。
- 我已经跟他说过你要来的原因了。

"虽然我…但我…因此我" is usually shortened as "我虽然…但…因此"

"而已" Why? I don't see how it is used.

"后果" is usually something bad, and is always used to imply the consequence/effect of something. It cannot be used alone.

- 你有没有考虑过徇私枉法的后果？√（下场/结果x）
- 现在锒铛入狱才后悔当初没有多想想贪污腐败的后果。√（下场√结果x）
- 上述两句区别在于，“下场”必定是已成现实/假定已成现实。
- 现在家道中落，祖荫尽失，可谓是不思进取的后果。√（结果/下场√）（贬损的语气下场＞后果＞结果）
- 这样做不用担心有什么后果。√（结果/下场x）
- 树倒猢狲散，飞扬跋扈的王家没落得个好后果。x（结果/下场√）
- 利用政策套利，目前还没发现有什么后果。√（结果/下场x）

Should 儿化音 be written down or not? I recommend not.