# Is there a difference between 连朋友都没告诉过 and 即便是朋友也没有告诉过?

Tags: difference

Comparing [Toosky Hierot's answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36113/8099) to my original attempt in [Writing critique request: Zhou Ziwang loses weight, just like everyone else nowadays](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36111/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-loses-weight-just-like-everyone-else-nowa), we have:

> me: ...**连**朋友**都**没告诉过...
>   Toosky Hierot: ...**即便**是朋友**也**没有告诉过...

I think both mean:

> Even [my] friends, [I] did not tell.

I'm not sure if there's any difference here, aside from perhaps writing style.  We've opted for different grammar constructs: [连...都...](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22even%22_with_%22lian%22_and_%22dou%22) vs. 即便...也... which I think is the same as [即使...也...](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22even_if%E2%80%A6%22_with_%22jishi%22) (which seems to necessitate the 是).

**Question**: Is there a difference between 连朋友都没告诉过 and 即便是朋友也没有告诉过?

Comment: Quite the same with small difference. In fact, I even prefer 连……都……here now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 连朋友都没告诉过 = Had not told even his friends

~

> 即便(是)朋友也没有告诉过(他们) =  Even though they (are) his friends, he had not told (them)

Notice:

即便 means "even though" or "even if"

There's a verb "是" (being) in "是朋友" (being friends)

More example:

> 连他父母也不知道他是同性恋 = Even his parents don't know he is gay
>
> 即便(是他父母)也不知道他是同性恋 = Even though (they are his parent), they don't know he is gay

Example of 即便:

> 即便(有)朋友也不能告诉(他们) = Even if/ even though he (has) friends, he can't tell (them)

~

> 即便全国警察都来了也救不了死去的人质了 (Even if) the police of the whole country were here, the dead hostages could not be saved.