# Writing critique request: Welcome to the world of DNA editing

Tags: writing-critique

Continuing from parts [1](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-and-the-revolutionary-new-technology), [2](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35763/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-was-fat-when-she-was-young), [3](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwangs-father-takes-her-to-the-doctor), [4](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35870/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-gets-an-injection-from-the-doctor), [5](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36003/writing-critique-request-the-almost-imperceptible-effects-of-zhou-ziwangs-inje), and [6](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36111/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-loses-weight-just-like-everyone-else-nowa):

> 欢迎来到现代的“DNA[编辑](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BC%96%E8%BE%91)的新世界”。原来我差不多是第一个DNA编辑的人，而且我爸是世界上领导的研究者[之一](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B9%8B%E4%B8%80)，一起偷偷地进行研究。我小时候[造成](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%80%A0%E6%88%90)我减肥的那个注射器是这种新技术的一个例子。那时候这项技术刚开始[研发](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%A0%94%E5%8F%91)了，所以当时是非常基础的。起初，多数人无法使用甚至连DNA编辑的存在也不知道。世界政府立即[介入](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BB%8B%E5%85%A5)了，都希望成为[唯一](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%94%AF%E4%B8%80)的国家能利用这项技术，在这个研究方向中建立[占主导](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8D%A0%E4%B8%BB%E5%AF%BC)的地位。不过现在DNA编辑为普通人能简单地使用。

Please critique my writing. New words for me are in links. I'm at an "almost mastered HSK4" level. The narrative is from a person in the present (Zhou Ziwang 周子望) with an unusual past.

- I've looked carefully and honestly don't believe there's any outright errors here.  So if they exist, they're something I'm blind to.
- I'm terrible at 了ing, so something like 开始研发了 vs. 开始了研发 vs. 开始研发 is very hard for me.  So I just copy/paste them into Baidu, and copy something similar like 6G开始研发了<sup>[[src]](https://tieba.baidu.com/p/6327709561?red_tag=3326653824)</sup>.
- My impression is that Chinese people say DNA using English letters and not the impractically long [脱氧核糖核酸](http://youdao.com/w/DNA).
- I like 占 in 占主导的地位 since the idea is that governments want to establish dominance, and are even blocking other countries, so there's a bit of tension.

Comment: "DNA editing" means "gene editing" (基因修改) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genome_editing

Comment: "DNA编辑的新世界" sounds like "the new world edited by DNA" in Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

欢迎来到现代“DNA编辑”的新世界。原来我差不多是第一个**接受**DNA编辑的人，而且我爸是**这个领域**的领导研究者之一，**他们**一起偷偷地进行研究。小时候**使**我**变瘦**的**药物**是这种新技术的一项**成果**。那时候这项技术刚开始研发，所以还比较**初级**，多数人**无缘**使用甚至根本不知道存在DNA编辑。**不久**，**各国**政府就介入了**这个领域**，都希望成为**能利用这项技术的唯一国家**，在研究中占主导地位。不过现在，DNA编辑技术**也**能简单地为普通人所用了。

Comments：

引号用在“DNA编辑”上以第一次介绍这个科学名词就可以了。

上文“DNA编辑”是作名词用的，这里需要谓语“接受”

“这个领域”作定语限定范围。

“一起”这个词必须搭配复数行为主体，原句主语是我爸，他一个人是不能“一起”研究的，需要切换主语。

“造成”一般接不利、不希望看到的影响/后果，这里应该用中性的“使”。（题主所提供的链接之例句似乎已经表明了这一点。）

“减肥”是主观行动，“变瘦”才是减肥的实际结果。（这件事似乎之前提过唔？）

“注射器”只是注射药物的工具，“药物”才是他们研究的成果。

“例子”用词不当。应该用“成果”。

很遗憾“刚开始研发了”反而不能加“了”。（但“开始研发了”却可以。）

“基础”用词不当。应该用“初级”。从逻辑上看，后面马上接“普通人难以接触这项技术”的句子，这里用“罕见”似乎更加合理。

“无法”用词不当。只是因为能实施这种技术的机构一开始非常有限，大部分人没有机会使用，而不是这种技术对他们无效。所以应该用“无缘”。

本句“无法使用”宾语缺失，将“DNA编辑”挪到句尾，将“不知道存在”整体作为谓语，使“DNA编辑”成为两个谓语的共同宾语。

“立即”时间词用得不好。“立即”的前文，需要存在明确的时间点，才能确认“立即”到底是什么时候。改成“不久”模糊一下比较好。

“世界政府”在汉语中专指辖制世界的政府，依文意，这里说的是“各国政府”。

“介入”缺宾语。

现代汉语中，宾语可以前置，定语却不能随便后置。所以应该是“能利用这项技术的唯一国家”。

句式杂糅。“建立主导地位”或“占主导地位”只能择一。

最后一句句式不明。如果要用“为……所……”的被动式，两个字都不能缺。

添加“也”顺畅逻辑。

Comment: 嗯，上次你说提了变瘦和减肥的区别。我责备自己英语说的习惯，用英语说“become thin"（变瘦）是不自然的。不好意思。

Answer (score 1):

*欢迎来到现代的“DNA编辑的新世界”*。 --> [欢迎来到「基因改造」的新世界]

*原来我差不多是第一个DNA编辑的人，* --> [我几乎可以说是第一个接受过基因改造的人]

*而且我爸是世界上领导的研究者之一， 一起偷偷地进行研究。*--> [我爸是这项科技的尖端研究者之一，与其他研究者一样，在偷偷研究这项枝术。]

*我小时候造成我减肥的那个注射器是这种新技术的一个例子。* --> [小时候帮我减肥的那个注射器，就是应用这种新技术的一个例子。]

*那时候这项技术刚开始研发了，所以当时是非常基础的。* --> [那时候这还是一项刚起步，也很原始的技术。]

*起初，多数人无法使用甚至连DNA编辑的存在也不知道。* --> [初时大多数人甚至连「基因改造技术」的存在也不知道，更不用说使用这项技术了，]

*世界政府立即介入了，都希望成为唯一的国家能利用这项技术，* --> [在当时，各国政府都即时介入了，希望成为唯一能利用这项技术的国家，]

*在这个研究方向中建立占主导的地位。*--> [在这个研究方向中占主导地位。]

*不过现在DNA编辑为普通人能简单地使用。* --> [但到了现在，一般人也能轻易地使用基因改造技术了。]

Note:

- If you consider 基因改造 too Chinese, you can use "DNA 改造/修改"
- "普通人能简单地使用" suggests everyone, even you and I can easily use it
- If you meant "common people can easily obtain this service", the sentence should be  "普通人也能轻易地得到这项服务"

Comment: ”everyone, even you and I can easily use it“ <-- this is what I mean