# Writing critique request: Upgrading your DNA is like upgrading software on your computer

Tags: writing-critique

Continuing from parts [1](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-and-the-revolutionary-new-technology), [2](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35763/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-was-fat-when-she-was-young), [3](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwangs-father-takes-her-to-the-doctor), [4](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35870/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-gets-an-injection-from-the-doctor), [5](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36003/writing-critique-request-the-almost-imperceptible-effects-of-zhou-ziwangs-inje), [6](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36111/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-loses-weight-just-like-everyone-else-nowa), and [7](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36218/writing-critique-request-welcome-to-the-world-of-dna-editing):

> 我们不知道谁在互联网上[泄露](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%B3%84%E9%9C%B2)了这个发明，但是以后，几乎每个电子公司开始提供[廉价](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BB%89%E4%BB%B7)的[适配器](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%80%82%E9%85%8D%E5%99%A8)。有的人认为免费[开源](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%BC%80%E6%BA%90)（FOSS）[社区](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%A4%BE%E5%8C%BA)[发挥](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%8F%91%E6%8C%A5)了作用。如果拥有电脑，像把软件[更新](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0)一样，现在你可以在网上[更新](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0)自己的DNA。
>
> 社会的态度完全改变了：起初，没人想要[编辑](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BC%96%E8%BE%91)自己的DNA，但很快发现了“DNA[优化](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BC%98%E5%8C%96)人”有许多巨大的竞争[优势](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BC%98%E5%8A%BF)。如果你不愿意[维护](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%BB%B4%E6%8A%A4)最新自己的DNA，就找不到工作、做什么事都比别人慢、交[恋人](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%81%8B%E4%BA%BA)也很难等。总之，人们不得不接受大家需要一直[安装](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85)[更新](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0)，否则不会成功。

Please critique my writing. New words for me are in links. I'm at the early stages of HSK5-level Chinese. The narrative is from a person in the present (Zhou Ziwang 周子望) with an unusual past.

Comments:

- The [适配器](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%80%82%E9%85%8D%E5%99%A8) refers to a (fictional) device installable in a human body which allows you to edit your DNA via a computer [like in *The Matrix*, but for editing DNA].  I'm not sure if 适配器 is the best term here.
- [更新](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9B%B4%E6%96%B0) is new for me, and I'm not completely comfortable with it; it might not even be the right word.
- > 有的人认为免费开源（FOSS）社区**发挥了作用**。
  >   Some people believe [the] free-and-open-source community **played a role**.

  I'm worried about this: in this idiomatic expression, the Chinese seems *too similar* to the English.
- I'm not sure if 很难等 would be mistaken for "difficult to wait" rather than "difficult, and so on".

I hope it's not too bad; I'm blind to any mistakes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I see no significant mistakes, congratulations!

我们不知道谁在互联网上泄露了这个发明，但是**那之后**，几乎每个电子公司**都**开始廉价提供**为人们安装DNA编辑接口的服务**。有的人认为免费开源社区发挥了作用。现在，如果**你**拥有电脑，**就能**像更新软件一样，藉由接口用计算机更新自己的DNA。

**社会上对此的态度发生过巨大的转折**：起初，没人想要编辑自己的DNA，但很快发现了“DNA优化人”有许多巨大的竞争优势，**导致现在**如果你不愿意维护自己的DNA到最新状态，就找不到工作、做什么事都比别人慢、**处对象**也很难**等等**。总之，人们不得不接受了大家需要一直安装更新，否则不能成功**的现实**。

“以后”指说话时间之后，而“之后”才跟着一个特定的时刻，表示“在那之后”。

“几乎每个电子公司开始提供廉价的适配器”这句话表意非常不好。如解释所说，这是一种安装在人身上，能够实现通过计算机编辑人体DNA功能的器件。但“适配器”本来是连结两不兼容接口的器件，而人体本来根本没有连接计算机的渠道，所以这里最好名之为“接口”（interface），意指为人体提供一个面向外界操作的渠道。第一次提到时，最好用“DNA编辑接口”来明确其意义，下文就可以用“接口”简单指代了。另外，我猜想这种硬件不是用户能随意设置的，所以公司提供“安装服务”似乎更合理。

主语虽然能够不在第一个分句出现，如：

但凡多吃几粒花生米，你也不至于醉成这样。

但“现在”这个时间词插在中间割裂了分句之间的关系，造成前面的分句缺少主语。作为修饰整个句子的时间，应该提到最前面去。然后再用“如果...就...”关联词是最自然的做法。另外“在网上更新自己的DNA”听起来像更新你的网络个人DNA档案，而非真正操作了自己人体的DNA，这里需要消歧义。

“社会的态度完全改变了”将时间点拉到了“态度改变”的结果，但是冒号后又从“改变之前”的状况说起，有一些错乱。将“了”替换成“过”，这样从“起初”说到“现在”比较自然。

“DNA优化人”有巨大的优势，但后文并不在说这种优势是什么（比如更美丽、聪明、灵巧等等），而是由优势带来的未做优化的人的不利处境，应该用“导致”，同时最好加“现在”时间词。

“交恋人”这个说法比较生硬，替换成等价的短语。

用“等等”就没有问题了。

“接受”缺宾语，是“接受...的现实”。

Answer (score 1):

我们不知道谁在互联网上泄露了这个发明，**但是以后， **几乎每个电子公司开始提供廉价的适配器。

- 但是以后: But later on (xxxxx), you don't need a comma between.

> 我们不知道谁在互联网上泄露了这个发明，**但是以后**几乎每个电子公司开始提供廉价的适配器。

**有的人**认为免费开源（FOSS）社区发挥了作用。

有的人: some of the people, usually you are referring to a group of people you have mentioned before but you didn't here, use 有人 instead

有人: someone

> **有人**认为免费开源（FOSS）社区发挥了作用。

**如果拥有电脑，像把软件更新一样**，现在你可以在网上更新自己的DNA。

> **就像电脑软件更新**，现在你可以在网上更新自己的DNA。

**社会的态度**完全改变了：

社会的态度 : the attitude of society

社会态度 : the society's attitude

> **社会态度**完全改变了：

起初没人**想要**编辑自己的DNA，但很快发现了“DNA优化人”有许多巨大的竞争优势。

想要: apply to objects, e.g. 我想要你 (I want to have you)

想: apply to actions, e.g.  我想你 (I want you/ I miss you)

> 起初没人**想**编辑自己的DNA，但很快发现了“DNA优化人”有许多巨大的竞争优势。

如果你不愿意**维护**最新自己的DNA，**就**找不到工作、做什么事都比别人慢、交恋人也很难**等**。

维护: means repair/fix use 维持 instead

维持: maintain

很难等: if you need to list out examples, you need to provide the category of your examples, like 困扰 (worries).

就会有.....等困扰: you will have worries such as ....

> 如果你不愿意**维持**最新自己的DNA，**就会有**找不到工作、做什么事都比别人慢、交恋人也很难**等困扰**。

总之，人们不得不接受大家需要一直**安装更新**，否则**不会成功**。

安装更新: install updates ,更新 can be use as a verb already, you can just say 更新DNA: update DNA

不会成功: you are missing the subject of this bit, what kind of things won't work/succeed?

> 总之，人们不得不接受大家需要一直**更新DNA**，否则**生活不会成功**。

Answer (score 1):

更新 mean makes somethings new or later version, it is completely fine to use it here.

免费开源 is also acceptable for me.

交恋人也很难等 can be ambiguity, but I think it is more logical to interpret it as difficult and so on, since you are not in a waiting list and line or wait for a specific time. and if you mean it is difficult and so on you can delete 等 to make it not ambiguous if you want. While I don't think you must delete. Both delete and not delete is ok.